# How can I analyze the disk space requirements of my IMAP mailbox?

Tags: email, imap, disk-space

For filesystems there are tolls like `du`, `ncdu`, or `baobab`. Is there something like this for mailboxes? That way I could quickly identify which folders use the most disk space.

Answer (score 0):

These tools can actually be used. My mail client - evolution - stores its local cache under `~/.cache/evolution/mail/<some mailbox ID>/folders/`.
There the folders have clear text names and can be analyzed for example with `ncdu`.

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if the client has cached the whole mailbox, which is not always the case.